# 'String' is not a subtype of type 'bool'

Tags: database, flutter, sqflite

This is a todo list app which uses a database. I am using a boolean variable `isDone` to mark a task as complete but when i add a new task, i get the error `'String' is not a subtype of type 'bool'`. I want to change the  value of `isDone` to string but i am unsure on where exactly i can type the `.toString()` line.

Tried using the solution for similar errors (int, bool, future is not a subtype of string, bool, etc.) but could'nt solve it because those errors were application specific.

database code :

```
 //This is the database

  String _itemName;
  String _dateCreated;
  int _id;
  bool _isDone;


  TodoItem(this._itemName, this._dateCreated, this._isDone);

  TodoItem.map(dynamic obj) {
    this._itemName = obj["itemName"];
    this._dateCreated = obj["dateCreated"];
    this._id = obj["id"];
    this._isDone = obj["isDone"];
  }

  String get itemName => _itemName;
  String get dateCreated => _dateCreated;
  int get id => _id;
  bool get isDone => _isDone;
  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    var map = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    map["itemName"] = _itemName;
    map["dateCreated"] = _dateCreated;
    map["isDone"] = _isDone;

    if (_id != null) {
      map["id"] = _id;
    }

    return map;
  }

  TodoItem.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    this._itemName = map["itemName"];
    this._dateCreated = map["dateCreated"];
    this._id = map["id"];
    this._isDone = map["isDone"];
  }
```

database create, update functions :

NOTE: the update function is only supposed to change the value of isDone

```
 Future<bool> updateItem(TodoItem item) async {
    var dbClient = await db;
    int res =   await dbClient.update("id", item.toMap(),
        where: "id = ?", whereArgs: <bool>[item.isDone]);
    return res > 0 ? true : false;
  }
```

```
  Future<int> saveItem(TodoItem item) async {
    var dbClient = await db;
    int res = await dbClient.insert("$tableName", item.toMap());
    print(res.toString());
    return res;
  }
```

Comment: Can you post that json as well, might ne map["isDone"] is coming in string for e.x "true"

Comment: sqflite doesn't support boolean.It stores boolean value as 1 or 0 (i.e in the form of int) .Try using <int> instead of <bool>.Please let me know if it works or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bool` are [not supported in SQLite](https://github.com/tekartik/sqflite/blob/master/sqflite/doc/supported_types.md#supported-sqlite-types).

What is likely happening is that the `isDone` column value `true` is converted to the string `"true"` so it is crashing in your `TodoItem.map` constructor.

Try to convert (and parse) the value for example to 1 or 0 (int) before insertion or in query args.

Answer (score 3):

This error appear on Flutter when bool x = string value assigned in the code. Unfortunately, there is no conversion from string to bool in Dart. One simple trick is to put something like this

```
String test = "true";
bool isCorrect = test == 'true';
```

This works as expected because the code will compare value of string and bool as strings and return the result as bool. You may need to use .toLowerCase() or .toUpperCase() according to your string value before the second line of the code above.